# How to fix this error [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'FDQA_TransTable'

Tags: sql-server, csv, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

[image: Error message when clicking "1.) Move text to table"]

I am trying to run this sample project by Embarcadero on Delphi 11 Enterprise with no changes to the source code:
Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDBatchMove\Main

and after logging into the database (using the dropdown menu and selecting "MSSQL_Demo") and clicking "1.) Move text to table" I encounter this error "Invalid object name 'FDQA_TransTable'."

I was trying to dig down to the actual line where the error occurs (using F7/trace into) but this is the furthest I can go before the error message comes up:

FDBatchMove.Execute;

[image: Code where error happens]

Heres the stack trace in case this helps.

[image: stack trace]

Heres my MSSQL version in case this helps.

[image: MSSQL version]

Are there additional steps I need to do before I am able to run this sample project? Maybe do something with the database like add tables or setup permissions? This is my first time setting up MSSQL and using FireDAC.

Comment: You probably need to open a ticket with Embarcadero support about that. The error is telling you that the `FDQA_TransTable` table doesn't exist in the database to which the demo app is connected. All of the `TFDBatchMove` (Sample) docs online are [very old](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FireDAC.TFDBatchMove_Sample) (for versions 10 and 11) and only mention that it works with Access and SQLite databases.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are correct. They have confirmed that the sample is only for Access and SQLite. Thank you!

I misunderstood because an MSSQL is available in the drop down.

I will be closing this question. By any chance, do you know if there is a sample project similar to this where CSV is converted and saved in MSSQL?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I just built everything from scratch (CSV to MSSQL). I was hoping an off the shelf solution was available.